# Método getJSON en Laravel 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Llevo un par de días intentando encontrar una solución pero no la encuentro (soy un poco torpe), por eso recurro a vosotros. Soy nuevo en `Laravel`, así que no me echéis la bronca si digo alguna burrada.

Estoy intentando pasar datos de una base de datos a una página Web a través de una solicitud `AJAX` con el método `getJSON` de `jQuery`, para después manipularlos (ordenar, filtrar, etc.), sin embargo, no hay respuesta alguna, ni se muestran errores. No se qué es lo que falla.

Mi route (routes.php):

```
Route::get('musica','MusicaController@getIndex');
```

Mi controlador (MusicaController.php):

```
class MusicaController extends Controller {

    public function getIndex() {
        return View::make('musica');
    }

    public function getMusica() {
        $musica = \DB::table('Musica')
        ->select('Titulo', 'Ano', 'Pais')
        ->orderBy('Ano', 'DESC')
        ->get();

        return Response::json($musica);   
    }
}
```

Mi vista (en un script) (musica.blade.php):

```
$(function() {
    $("#boton").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".prueba3").html("CARGANDO...");

        $.getJSON("/musica", function(data) {
            var mimusic = "";       
            $.each(data, function() {
                mimusic += this.Titulo + " - " + this.Ano  + "<br>";
            })
            $(".prueba3").html(mimusic);
        }); // getJSON

    }); // Click
}); // function
```

**Edición** basada en la respuesta de Horacio:

No estoy tratando de devolver datos desde la vista sino pasar los datos del controlador a la vista para allí manipularlos con `jQuery`.

El formato que estaba usando para hacer el response es el de `Laravel 4` y gracias a esa respuesta ya sé que no es el adecuado pero tampoco me funciona con el formato de `Laravel 5`.

Ya he estado mirando la documentación pero no ayuda mucho y menos para los que empicezan con Laravel.

Dices que debo obtener los datos como arreglo, ¿y esto qué devuelve?:

```
$musica = \DB::table('Musica')
->select('Titulo', 'Ano', 'Pais')
->orderBy('Ano', 'DESC')
->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

Para devolver los datos de la vista en formato JSON, deberías usar

```
public function getIndex() {
    // debes obtener los datos como arreglo
    $datos = [["titulo": "Titulo1", "Ano": "año1"], ...]];

    //Así es el return en laravel 4
    return Response::json($datos);

    // Así en laravel 5
    return response()->json($datos);
 }
```

Más información sobre respuestas aquí:

- [Views & Responses](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses) (versión 4)
- [HTTP Responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses) (versión 5)

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar el metodo `toJson()` con el `return` directamente, así:

```
  $musica = \DB::table('Musica')
    ->select('Titulo', 'Ano', 'Pais')
    ->orderBy('Ano', 'DESC')
    ->get()
    ->toJson();

  return $musica;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes un modelo música, podrías usar:

```
$musica = Musica::select('titulo', 'ano', 'pais')
      ->orderBy('Ano', 'DESC')
      ->get();

return $response->json($musica->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu petición con JQuery te diriges a la ruta "/musica", eso llama al método index de tu controlador (MusicaController.php), crea una ruta que llame al método (getMusica) de tu controlador.

```
Route::get('musica/show', [
    'uses'  => 'MusicaController@getMusica',
    'as'    => 'musica.show'
]);
```

Ahora puede acceder a usa ruta con una petición AJAX

```
$(function() {
    $("#boton").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".prueba3").html("CARGANDO...");

        $.getJSON("musica/show", function(data) {
            var mimusic = "";       
            $.each(data, function() {
                mimusic += this.Titulo + " - " + this.Ano  + "<br>";
            })
            $(".prueba3").html(mimusic);
        }); // getJSON

    }); // Click
}); // function
```

No olvides que en Laravel se usa TOKEN (csrf-x-xsrf-token) para tener peticiones seguras.

Puedes leer más en la documentación oficial.
[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#quick-ajax-requests-and-validation)